# How to use AppManage in running selected instances in Tibco

Tags: bash, instance, tibco, tibco-business-works, app-manager

I would like to run selected instances of a Tibco service.

I understand that in running the following lines you would be able to run a specific instance:

```
./AppManage -start -app [some_app_tree] -domain [some_domain] -cred [some_cred] -service [some_service] -binding [instance_name_1]
```

But what if I would also like to run instance_name_3 and instance_name_6, ignoring the other instances?

I was trying this:

```
./AppManage -start -app [some_app_tree] -domain [some_domain] -cred [some_cred] -service [some_service] -binding [instance_name_1] [instance_name_3] [instance_name_6]
```

But its not working. Any kind of help would do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the case where -binding is provided without -service, all services in the
application are started.

```
AppManage -start -app myApp -binding ActiveDatabaseAdapterConfiguration -user a -pw a -domain test
```